# How to add a counter number to a variable and the selector on click in jquery

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm using rangeslider.js in a small app where users can add new section with a click. I'm able to duplicate the section but need to make the variable and selector unique for the new section in order to make the second range slider work. So How can I make the variable and its selector used for the range slider unique with each click.

```js
var jQuerytsBlurSlider = jQuery('#text-s-blur-range');
var jQuerytsBlurAmount = jQuery('#text-s-blur-input');

jQuerytsBlurSlider
  .rangeslider({
    polyfill: false
  })
  .on('input', function() {
    jQuerytsBlurAmount[0].value = this.value;
  });

jQuerytsBlurAmount.on('input', function() {
  jQuerytsBlurSlider.val(this.value).change();
});

var shadowCount=1;

function addShadow() {

 shadowCount++;

 shadowDiv=document.getElementById("shadows-container");
 buttonsDiv=document.getElementById("shadow-buttons");
 
 nodeToClone=document.getElementById('shadow-container')
 nextShadowContainer=nodeToClone.cloneNode(true);
 nextTextShadowContainer=nodeToClone.cloneNode(true);
 nextShadowContainer.id="shadow-container"+shadowCount;
 nextTextShadowContainer.id="text-s-blur-range"+shadowCount;

 shadowDiv.insertBefore(nextShadowContainer, buttonsDiv);
 nextShadowContainer.childNodes[1].innerText="Shadow " + shadowCount;
 
 for (i=0; i<nextShadowContainer.childNodes.length; i++) {
  nextShadowContainer.childNodes[i].id=nextShadowContainer.childNodes[i].id +shadowCount;  
 }
 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.3/rangeslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.3.3/rangeslider.min.js"></script>

<div id="shadows-container">
  <div class="shadow-option" id="shadow-container">
    <h2>Shadow</h2>
    <div class="row" id="sh-blur">
      <label>Blur</label>
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="col-wrap">
            <input type="range" id="text-s-blur-range" value="0" min="0" max="100" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="col-wrap">
            <input type="number" id="text-s-blur-input" value="0" min="0" max="100" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="shadow-buttons">
    <button class="repeat" onClick="addShadow()">Add Another</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to change all #id from your div if you want to clone or repeat it..id must be unique so class is best here. After that you need to duplicate only the container and set unique-id.. then create a new rangeslider and prepend to the duplicate container..and init with the right id of slider
I will not post all the code but look at exemples on codepen im sure you will be inspired..

```
<div class="shadows-container" id="shadow-1">
<input type="range" class="text-s-blur-range">
```

Another idea would be to have some hidden duplicate rangeslider and only to show each if "add shadow" is clicked